# Android Intent for IONIC PWA

Tags: ionic-framework, android-intent, ionic3, progressive-web-apps

I understand that current implementation of intent can work only with Ionic Native

Is it possible to make it work in PWA ... Say web intent? 
From PWA (aka web app) I want to send intent to app on same mobile device.
What are the limitations in making it available in PWA say as npm angular module instead of Cordova plugin

Does anyone have any implementation that can makes web intent work in PWA?

Comment: So those APIs are quite fragmented and might be browser specific. Are you looking into something like https://branch.io/glossary/chrome-intents/ ?

Comment: Yes. Similar. I have seen it. However I want to go one step further.

Comment: I want to go one step further. Sender app sends an intent to target app. Target app should be able to process and act on the intent which chrome intent does. Thereafter chrome should send response back and dene should receive response. Example use case... Initiate payment request, target app would be a payment wallet app or booking app.

Comment: Also I understand the api is browser specific. Hence is it possible to build browser agnostic implementation of intent that can be used in PWA. Similar to Cordova nati ve  plugin ... Cordova plugins are native. Can there be angular wrapper for Android intent